# D3.js brush behaviour fires two 'end' events

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

So, implementing a brush behaviour inspired from [M Bostock example](https://gist.github.com/mbostock/6498580) I came across something I did not quite understand.
If set a callback for the 'end' event of the brush, this gets called as expected whenever you're interacting directly with the brush.
But whenever I recenter the brush, it seems that the end event is fired twice.
Why is that the case? Or, is it something I'm doing wrong here?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style>

.selected {
  fill: red;
  stroke: brown;
}

</style>
<svg width="960" height="150"></svg>
<div>Event fired <span id="test"></span></div>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

var fired=0;
var randomX = d3.randomUniform(0, 10),
    randomY = d3.randomNormal(0.5, 0.12),
    data = d3.range(800).map(function() { return [randomX(), randomY()]; });

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {top: 10, right: 50, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 10])
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var brush = d3.brushX()
    .extent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
    .on("start brush", brushed)
   .on("end", brushend);

var dot = g.append("g")
    .attr("fill-opacity", 0.2)
  .selectAll("circle")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d[0]) + "," + y(d[1]) + ")"; })
    .attr("r", 3.5);

g.append("g")
    .call(brush)
    .call(brush.move, [3, 5].map(x))
  .selectAll(".overlay")
    .each(function(d) { d.type = "selection"; }) // Treat overlay interaction as move.
    .on("mousedown touchstart", brushcentered); // Recenter before brushing.

g.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

function brushcentered() {
  var dx = x(1) - x(0), // Use a fixed width when recentering.
      cx = d3.mouse(this)[0],
      x0 = cx - dx / 2,
      x1 = cx + dx / 2;
  d3.select(this.parentNode).call(brush.move, x1 > width ? [width - dx, width] : x0 < 0 ? [0, dx] : [x0, x1]);
}

function brushed() {
  var extent = d3.event.selection.map(x.invert, x);
  dot.classed("selected", function(d) { return extent[0] <= d[0] && d[0] <= extent[1]; });
}


function brushend() {
  document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = ++fired;
// console.log('end fired - ' + (++fired));
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you want to stop an event from triggering multiple layers of actions, you can use:

```
d3.event.stopPropagation();
```

Here you can include it at the end of the `brushcentered` function:

```
function brushcentered() {
  var dx = x(1) - x(0), // Use a fixed width when recentering.
  cx = d3.mouse(this)[0],
  x0 = cx - dx / 2,
  x1 = cx + dx / 2;
  d3.select(this.parentNode).call(brush.move, x1 > width ? [width - dx, width] : x0 < 0 ? [0, dx] : [x0, x1]);
  d3.event.stopPropagation();
}
```

And the demo:

```html
<style>

.selected {
  fill: red;
  stroke: brown;
}

</style>
<svg width="960" height="150"></svg>
<div>Event fired <span id="test"></span></div>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

var fired=0;
var randomX = d3.randomUniform(0, 10),
    randomY = d3.randomNormal(0.5, 0.12),
    data = d3.range(800).map(function() { return [randomX(), randomY()]; });

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {top: 10, right: 50, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 10])
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var brush = d3.brushX()
    .extent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
    .on("start brush", brushed)
   .on("end", brushend);

var dot = g.append("g")
    .attr("fill-opacity", 0.2)
  .selectAll("circle")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d[0]) + "," + y(d[1]) + ")"; })
    .attr("r", 3.5);

g.append("g")
    .call(brush)
    .call(brush.move, [3, 5].map(x))
  .selectAll(".overlay")
    .each(function(d) { d.type = "selection"; }) // Treat overlay interaction as move.
    .on("mousedown touchstart", brushcentered); // Recenter before brushing.

g.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

function brushcentered() {
  var dx = x(1) - x(0), // Use a fixed width when recentering.
      cx = d3.mouse(this)[0],
      x0 = cx - dx / 2,
      x1 = cx + dx / 2;
  d3.select(this.parentNode).call(brush.move, x1 > width ? [width - dx, width] : x0 < 0 ? [0, dx] : [x0, x1]);
  d3.event.stopPropagation();
}

function brushed() {
  var extent = d3.event.selection.map(x.invert, x);
  dot.classed("selected", function(d) { return extent[0] <= d[0] && d[0] <= extent[1]; });
}


function brushend() {
  document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = ++fired;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks man, this did exactly what I wanted. I didn't take into account the fact that I can stop the event propagation

Comment: It seems that the stopping of the event propagation will make the user unable to recenter the brush and drag it along in one click.

Comment: Exact, although I'm not sure it's a common thing to do. If this is a requirement, you could potentially use the stopPropagation with additional logic to fit what you're expecting.

Answer (score 1):

**-UPDATE-**

For the purpose of this snippet, I can use a boolean flag to stop the first event and let the second go through. This means that I am still able to drag the brush after recentering, all in one go.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style>

.selected {
  fill: red;
  stroke: brown;
}

</style>
<svg width="960" height="150"></svg>
<div>Event fired <span id="test"></span></div>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

var fired=0;
var justcentered = false;
var randomX = d3.randomUniform(0, 10),
    randomY = d3.randomNormal(0.5, 0.12),
    data = d3.range(800).map(function() { 
      return [randomX(), randomY()];
    });

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = { top: 10, right: 50, bottom: 30, left: 50 },
    width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    g = svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 10])
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var brush = d3.brushX()
    .extent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
    .on("start brush", brushed)
   .on("end", brushend);

var dot = g.append("g")
      .attr("fill-opacity", 0.2)
    .selectAll("circle")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("circle")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { 
          return "translate(" + x(d[0]) + "," + y(d[1]) + ")";
        })
      .attr("r", 3.5);

g.append("g")
    .call(brush)
    .call(brush.move, [3, 5].map(x))
  .selectAll(".overlay")
    .each(function(d) { d.type = "selection"; }) // Treat overlay interaction as move.
    .on("mousedown touchstart", brushcentered); // Recenter before brushing.

g.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

function brushcentered() {
  var dx = x(1) - x(0), // Use a fixed width when recentering.
      cx = d3.mouse(this)[0],
      x0 = cx - dx / 2,
      x1 = cx + dx / 2;
 justcentered = true;
  d3.select(this.parentNode)
    .call(brush.move, x1 > width ? [width - dx, width] : x0 < 0 ? [0, dx] : [x0, x1]);
}

function brushed() {
  var extent = d3.event.selection.map(x.invert, x);
  dot.classed("selected", function(d) { return extent[0] <= d[0] && d[0] <= extent[1]; });
}


function brushend() {
 if(justcentered) {
    justcentered = false;
    return;
  }
  document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = ++fired;
}
</script>
```